# Generic datatype conversion best way

Tags: c#, .net

I have to handle multiple datatype conversion. I don't want to do separate individual conversion. Is there any way i can use a generic converter class which can solve this problem

kindly help!!!

update: how to make the argument generic as well

```
private static T GetValueForParameter<T>(int temp)
{ 
    T tempValue;
    tempValue = default(T);
    tempValue = (T)Convert.ChangeType(temp, typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return tempValue;
}
```

Comment: kindly expand, explain, show what you mean and study: [Ask]

Comment: Very unclear what you're trying to achieve here. Can you elaborate on it? Provide some examples of what you've tried/what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the argument being generic all you need is just define another template M like this.  updated your code use like this. Hope this answers your question.

```
private static T GetValueForParameter<T,M>(M temp)
{
    T tempValue;
    tempValue = default(T);
    tempValue = (T)Convert.ChangeType(temp, typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    return tempValue;
}
```

Comment: can you post calling method also

Comment: Why not just make the argument an object ... ?

Comment: float x = 20.0f;
int f= GetValueForParameter<int, float>(x);

Comment: Yes we can make argument as object but as asked in question they want to utilize generics in the solution so...

Comment: ChangeType won't work for all types though. Only IConvertible if I'm remembering correctly

Comment: Yes i'll update answer this will work with compatible types only because if there is no implicit conversion it will surely throw exception